# Div ul >li keep inside one line(Horizontal line)

Tags: html, css

I have a Div with Ul Li Right Now Everything is coming one by one(Vertically)

```
<div class="tm-extra-product-options-container">
   <ul class="tmcp-ul-wrap">
      <li class="tmcp-field-wrap">List One</li>
      <li class="tmcp-field-wrap">List Two</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

How Can I align Horizontal Please Give Some Idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is working demo, it is working demo...
you can run this code and check too.

```css
div ul li{display:inline;}
```

```html
   <div class="tm-extra-product-options-container">
   <ul class="tmcp-ul-wrap">
  <li class="tmcp-field-wrap">List One</li>
  <li class="tmcp-field-wrap">List Two</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Here it is working Can you please Check my updated Question

Comment: @websmentor.com i updated my answer, same css solve your problem, just have to change html code as you change, if it is helpful to you, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In your css code add.

```
div ul li{display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the following css

```
li{
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
list-style:none
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your code add this style in li:

```
li{
   display: inline-block;
   ....
}
```

For your reference http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
 ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 list-style:none;
}
```

Or

```
 ul li{
 float:left;
 list-style:none;
}
```

**Try It Once**